# 16.04 MariaDB -> Error in syslog (mysqlcheck)

Tags: 16.04, mysql, syslog, mariadb

i've found the following failure in my syslog after installing Ubuntu 16.04 and MariaDB from the Scratch using this really awesome tutorial
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-apache-with-php-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04-lamp/

```
    May 14 12:00:13 fortuna /etc/mysql/debian-start[1466]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
May 14 12:00:13 fortuna /etc/mysql/debian-start[1466]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
May 14 12:00:13 fortuna /etc/mysql/debian-start[1466]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
May 14 12:00:13 fortuna /etc/mysql/debian-start[1466]: Version check failed. Got the following error when calling the 'mysql' command line client
May 14 12:00:13 fortuna /etc/mysql/debian-start[1466]: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
May 14 12:00:13 fortuna /etc/mysql/debian-start[1466]: FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
May 14 12:00:13 fortuna /etc/mysql/debian-start[1487]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
May 14 12:00:13 fortuna mysql[1020]: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I've already created a .my.cnf in the /root directory.
If i run "mysql" as root i can login without a password. (See below)

```
root@fortuna:~# mysql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 7071
Server version: 10.0.24-MariaDB-7 Ubuntu 16.04


Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.


Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.


MariaDB [(none)]>
```

But if i try to use mysqlcheck check i get an error like this:

```
root@fortuna:~# /usr/bin/mysqlcheck --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf --all-databases --fast --silent
/usr/bin/mysqlcheck: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect
```

If i took a closer look then i found out that there is a file /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
which should contain the passwords.
But there is no password listed in there.
On the other hand i should not type it in here because it say's DO NOT TOUCH!
What shall I do?

```
# Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = 
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = 
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr
```

Comment: In spite of it being a bad idea, the "correct" action sounds like it's going to be to add the root password to that file.

Comment: If i do so, it works. I guess it is a problem  of the "mysql_secure_installation" script that it does not update the Values.

Comment: Okay, I've submitted a bug report.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mariadb-10.0/+bug/1582209

Answer (score 3):

Current most compatible solution in my case is to enter the root password in

```
 /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

In addition, I've submitted a bug report.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mariadb-10.0/+bug/1582209

Comment: I changed it to not use socket connection locally. So I had to change it there as well.

Answer (score 1):

try adding that text to your my.cnf and replace **--defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf** with **--defaults-file=~/.my.cnf** include your password.
your request got denied because debian.cnf overrides [client]. if .my.cnf looks like:

```
[client]
user=mysqluser
password=mysqlpass
```

Comment: If i update If the /etc/mysql/debian.cfg  it works. I guess it is a problem  of the "mysql_secure_installation" script that it does not update the Values.
I also assume it would work if i update the command line.
Where can I report the issue so that it is considered for further updates?

Comment: Okay, I've submitted a bug report.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mariadb-10.0/+bug/1582209
But thanks a lot for describing that the --defaults-file= option overrides the settings in .my.cnf